# SQL Server 2005 ignores else in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, exacttarget

I have a SQL query that runs to produce a list of bounced email addresses. The issue I'm having is that no matter what I do I don't get back anything when `b.SubscriberKey` is either 0 or non-existent. This works fine when `b.SubscriberKey` is greater than 0.

I believe it has something to do with doing a join on a table that may have no matching rows, but I would've believed that would have resulted in either a count of 0 or null. When I changed my query to test this, I still get nothing.

Edit: I'm looking for the string 'No Bounces' to appear the query runs on a day when I know in fact no bounces have occurred. When run currently the results is completely blank.

```
Select 
    case 
       when count(b.SubscriberKey) is not null 
          then b.SubscriberKey 
          else 'No bounces' 
    end as SubscriberKey
from 
    _bounce b
Join 
    _Job j with (nolock) on j.JobID = b.JobID
where 
    convert(date, b.EventDate) = convert(date, dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())) 
    and j.EmailID = 66653 
group by 
    b.SubscriberKey
```

Comment: what do you need as a result? Do you want 0 or NULL's to be displayed

Comment: Hi Santhosh, see my edit above.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: As a matter of efficiency you may want to look at changing the logic to use `NOT EXISTS` rather than `COUNT`. You don't seem to need a precise number, just the presence of a bounceback.

Answer (score 1):

from what I understood, you need Subscriberkeys with value 0 or NULLS also to be displayed in your result and you have also stated that it may not have records in that Join table. As you itself stated, in this scenario the best bet is LEFT Join and not INNER JOIN

```
Select case when b.SubscriberKey is not null then b.SubscriberKey else 'No bounces' end as SubscriberKey
from _Job j with (nolock)
LEFT Join _bounce b
on j.JobID = b.JobID
where convert(date,b.EventDate)=convert(date,dateadd(dd,-1,getdate())) 
and j.EmailID = 66653 
group by b.SubscriberKey
```

Comment: Hi Santhosh, I reran it but its still coming back blank when the else statement should be executed. I've also tried replacing the 'not null' clause with 0 and the issue still exists.

Comment: do u have 0 or NULL present in your data, have you checked it? if it is for five sample records you list out the result of CASE with SUBSCRIBERKEY values

Comment: Hi Santhosh, there aren't any 0 or NULLs. For example, I ran the query on a day I knew there were no bounced emails. If I run a simple query to return the SubscriberKeys I get no results. When I do a Count on that value it is 0, and should trigger my else statement.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. You need to get result out of the query when there are no records in Bounce table. The your base table is Job table, right? Even if a JobId is not present in Bounce table, you need this query to return 0 for that. Correct me if I am worng

Comment: made an edit. If that's the case, JOB should be used as base table and left join should be made to Bounce table.

Comment: Hi Santhosh, that didn't seem to change anything in terms of results

Comment: Remove the where condition for the EMAILID . If it is having record in Bounce you won't see it. There are also some records in Job which is not Bounce table otherwise you won't see "No Bounce" in results.

Comment: That won't help since I'm querying for bounces for a specific EmailID so it must be included somewhere.

Comment: use it after "on j.JobID = b.JobID' as "AND j.EmailID = 66653 ". But, remove it from WHERE

Comment: This is what I used and it still appears to be the same issue:     Select case when b.SubscriberKey is not null then b.SubscriberKey else 'No bounces' end as SubscriberKey
from _Job j with (nolock)
LEFT Join _bounce b
on j.JobID = b.JobID and j.EmailID = 66653 
where convert(date,b.EventDate)=convert(date,dateadd(dd,-3,getdate())) 
group by b.SubscriberKey